# Get total amount of memory on NUMA systems in Powershell

Tags: powershell, wmi, ram, numa

I'm trying to get the total amount of memory in a NUMA system.
My test system is a two socket physical server with 512GB of memory.
This are the methods I tried:

1. Win32_PhysicalMemory

   ```
   (Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory | Measure-Object -Property Capacity -Sum).Sum)/1GB
   ```

This returns 255.99 GB.

2. Cim_PhysicalMemory

   ```
   $MaxRam = 0
   $RamPool = (Get-CimInstance -Class "Cim_PhysicalMemory" | % {$_.Capacity})

   foreach ($RamBank in $RamPool) {
       $MaxRam += $RamBank/1024/1024
   }
   ```

This returns 255.99 GB.

As you can see I always get 256 GB as result. In the BIOS I see that each socket has 256 GB assigned to it. 
How can I get the memory for all NUMA-nodes?

A solution I thought of was take the amount of memory, found with above methods, and multiply it with the number of sockets.
Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: There is a number of Win32 functions regarding Numa and queries about a system configuration. While not being power shell oriented, this might grant you some insights into what you are looking for.

Comment: Try this: `$mem = gwmi win32_physicalmemory` and `$mem | % { $_.capacity / 1gb }`. Does iterating the `$mem` variable print reasonable memory amounts per node?

Comment: @vonPryz - It looks like you can't get the [entire picture on NUMA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45837347/52598) systems with default powershell cmdlets but I'd love to be corrected.

Comment: The first method works for me.  Your problem might be something other than NUMA.  Does `Win32_PhysicalMemory` show the correct number of DIMMs?